# How to restore mongo dmp file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I took my database backup to my AWS s3 bucket using [mongo-backup-to-s3](https://github.com/bradoyler/mongo-backup-to-s3). My back is a .dmp file. How can I restore the database to local / server? I have tried this code but now working.

```
mongorestore --port 27017 --db mongo_2017-01-10_13-18-00_dbname.dmp
```

Comment: What is your local mongodb version?

Comment: @Saleem db version v2.6.10

Answer (score 0):

The tool you linked clearly states that it is not compatible with mongodb 2.5+ thus you are out of luck, or not!

My suggestion is to install an old 2.4 version on your computer ([win](https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32/x86_64-2008plus-ssl), [linux](http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/redhat/os/x86_64/RPMS/)), restore the db and then upgrade db (to 2.6 or newer, I recommend NEWER!) and find out how the newer mongodb version do dump their data.